# Проблема с Django на винде

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, visual-studio-2017

Проблема в следующем:

1. В Django создал новое приложение (работаю visual studio 2017)
2. При запуске Django shell не импортироваться апликуха и соотвецтвенно модель
3. Получаем вот такое:

   ```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File ".\app\models.py", line 9, in <module>
     class Artist(models.Model):
   File ".\app\models.py", line 10, in Artist
     name = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
   File "django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1043, in __init__
     super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
   File "django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 166, in __init__
     self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
   File "django\conf\__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
     self._setup(name)
   File "django\conf\__init__.py", line 39, in _setup
     % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:
     Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured.
     You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
     or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
   ```
4. Здесь привожу manage.py

   ```py
   #!/usr/bin/env python
   """
   Command-line utility for administrative tasks.
   """

   import os
   import sys


   if __name__ == "__main__":
       os.environ.setdefault(
           "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE",
           "DataBaseFun.settings",
       )

       from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
   ```
5. Новая апликуха зарегистрирована.

   ```py
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
       'app',
       # Add your apps here to enable them
       'django.contrib.admin',
       'django.contrib.auth',
       'django.contrib.contenttypes',
       'django.contrib.sessions',
       'django.contrib.messages',
       'django.contrib.staticfiles',
   ]
   ```

Подскажите, уже все перелопатил, не нашел проблемы. Работаю на винде 10.Python 3 Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всем спасибо, за помощь, спустя 3 дня нашел решение.

- В случае с Pycharm, запускаем на винде с правами админа
- Через Visual Studio 2017 работает через консоль. Встроена оболочка Django не работает.

Answer (score 2):

Traceback говорит о том, что Вы пытаетесь что-то импортировать до того, как были инициализированы настройки.

Попробуйте сначала сказать в шелле

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "DataBaseFun.settings")
```

, а потом импортировать...

Comment: Все равно ошибка

django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.'

Comment: Какая версия Django? Покажите полный traceback

Comment: Django 1.11

http://prntscr.com/eu8d3u

Comment: теперь после `os.environ.setdefault(...)` попробуйте добавить `import django`, а потом `django.setup()`

Comment: Та же ошибка что и сверху(((